# MATLAB: How to increase the saturation of a grey-value images

Tags: matlab, image-processing, rgb

I know that I can change the saturation of a RGB image with `rgb2hsv`, but not for grey-value images. I've already tried the neighbourhood function. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: How do you define saturation?

Comment: True grayscale images (as opposed to RGB images that have be desaturated) only have one parameter that can be varied: gray level, which is akin to brightness.

Comment: Exactly.  The idea of saturation for grayscale is nonsensical to me.

Comment: To put it differently: the saturation of gray is 0 by definition. :-)

Comment: The effect you're looking for is probably not called saturation. Try to describe it better, or add a sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have pointed out, the saturation of a gray-scale image is 0 by definition.  If you are looking to improve contrast try `imadjust` or `histeq`.

Answer (score 0):

As has already been mentioned, "saturation" is not a term that can apply to a grayscale image.  Below is a suggestion that might approach the kind of effect you are imagining:

```
sat = 10;
imshow(img1,rgb2gray(map).^(exp(-0.1*sat)));
```

This assumes that your image `img1` has a corresponding colormap in `map`. If you have no colormap you can replace `rgb2gray(map)` with `gray(256)`.

In the example above, positive values of `sat` will produce brighter images, and negative values of `sat` will produce darker images. Really you can change the function that warps your colormap in whatever way you choose to get the desired effect.